# What Executable Icons/Thumbnails are Chosen by Windows?

Tags: icons, thumbnails, windres

The Visual compilers and GCC use .rc files to add resources to your executable. One can specify a resource type called `ICON`, to add an Icon to your executable. If I specify multiple `ICON`s in my .rc files, which one is chosen to be displayed as a thumbnail in the Windows explorer and which one is chosen to be displayed as the window icon, when the programm starts?

I conducted a few tests and it seems, that it allways chooses the same one to be displayed in the Windows Explorer as a thumbnail, but perhaps this is some caching done by windows. The Properties window from the Windows Explorer allways shows a different icon, perhaps one with the smallest size. The icon beeing displayed, when the program is executed differes (it might be the one, with the lowest value, described by `nameID` in the docs).

The official Windows docs do not answer this question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/icon-resource. I don't think there are any docs about this from gcc/windres specifically.

By the way, even though the docs clearly say...

> Defines a bitmap that defines the shape of the icon to be used for a given application or an animated icon.

...using a bmp file (exported by Windows Paint) is not accepted as an icon by windres (`windres: icon file 'bmpicon.bmp' does not contain icon data`).

I use gcc, as well as windres to compile the program, but I hope it wouldn't change the outcome, if I used the Visual compilers from Microsoft. In case it was still unclear: Windows is the operating system used.

I am unsure, if this is the correct forum to post such a question, but in case it isn't, I apologize.
Thanks in Advance for sharing hard to find information.